# Using a random instance of a class in a text

Tags: python, random

I am new to python and want to write a simple text adventure game. The player enters a tavern and interacts with the guests. The game takes place in a fantasy setting, where there are multiple races. I want to randomly generate each guest and then interact with them in the tavern. Here is my simplified code:

```
import random
class guest:
    def __init__(self,race,name,fav_food):
        self.race = race
        self.name = name
        self.fav_food = fav_food

guest1 = guest('human','Tom','chicken')

print('The first guest you meet is a '+guest1.race+ ' named '+guest1.name+ '. He really likes '+guest.fav_food+ '.')
```

So far so good. But here i get stuck: I want the set of data for guest1 to be randomly selected from other guests that i create beforehand.

```
guest1 = guest('human','Tom','chicken')
guest1 = guest('dwarf','Bjorn','potatoes')
guest1 = guest('orc','Orok','pork')
guest1 = guest('elf',,'Eli','Salad')
```

How do i do that? Sure, i could name them guest2,guest3 etc., but then it wouldn´t be random anymore.

When i run the code, i want to randomly encounter Tom,Bjorn,Orok or Eli

I would really appreciate any help on this matter.
Sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Put your guests in a *list*, then use `random.choice()` to pick one from the list at random. Or put the values for each of the 3 attributes in lists and use `guest(random.choice(races), random.choice(names), random.choice(fav_food))` to generate a new `guest` instance when you need one.

Answer (score 1):

You can put all of your guests into an array and use `random.choice` to set random guest to a variable called `random_guest`.

```
guests = [guest('human', 'Tom', 'chicken'),
          guest('dwarf', 'Bjorn', 'potatoes'),
          guest('orc', 'Orok', 'pork'),
          guest('elf', 'Eli', 'Salad')]

random_guest = random.choice(guests)
print('The first guest you meet is a '+ random_guest.race + ' named '+ random_guest.name + '. He really likes '+ random_guest.fav_food + '.')
```

Comment: You may want to remove the extra comma in the last element of ```guests```.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly fine [to use `random.choice` to select *one* character from a list of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52687790/2749397) but sometimes `random.choice` is not what  you want.

I mean, no problem if your game is *conversational*: you meet George, move on to Rita and next it's George again...

But, if your game implies that you KILL George (or George kills you... Game Over) then you KILL Rita, well it would be strange (unless your game is titled *Zombie34 — the Tavern Massacre*) if George comes back to harass you.

If your use case is the second one, I'd suggest using a combination of `random.shuffle`

```
characters = [...]
random.shuffle(characters)
```

and the `.pop` method of a list

```
# whenever you need a new character
try:
    a_character = characters.pop()
except IndexError:
    # if you are here, you have exausted your list of characters,
    # you could consider generating a new list and possibly starting a new level
```